# How can I save a dictionary to a text file with the order initially I assigned to it in Python?

Tags: python

I need to save some information of my data to the text file before saving the data matrix, but I found that the order is a little different from that I initially assigned to the dictionary. How can I keep the correct order? Here is my code:

```
headers = {}
headers["ncols"] = "184"
headers["nrows"] = "223"
headers["xllcorner"] = "0"
headers["yllcorner"] = "0"
headers["cellsize"] = "1000"
headers["NODATA_value"] = "-9999"
path = "DATA.txt"
with open(path, 'w') as f:
    for K, V in headerdict.items():
        f.write(K + "\t" + V + "\n")
```

This is the resulting file I get:
[Resulting text file I get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAtSB.png)

PS: Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ordereddict

```
from collections import OrderedDict

headers = OrderedDict()

headers = {}
headers["ncols"] = "184"
headers["nrows"] = "223"
headers["xllcorner"] = "0"
headers["yllcorner"] = "0"
headers["cellsize"] = "1000"
headers["NODATA_value"] = "-9999"

with open(r"D:\data\desktop-jul12016\Desktop This Week\demo.txt", 'w') as f:
    for K, V in headers.items():
        f.write(K + "\t" + V + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OrderedDict` data structure from `collections` module.

you can read more about it [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It helps me.